# Почему не присваивается значение возвращаемой переменной

Tags: c#

Осваиваю С#,пытаюсь написать метод для проверки существования определенного текста, объявил переменную nameIsOK и пытаюсь присвоить ей значение, но получаю сообщение что возвращаемая переменная не имеет присвоенного мной значения. Как мне исправить код?

```
public bool CheckTheSectionName(string sectionName)
    {
        var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        var db = doc.Database;
        var ed = doc.Editor;
        bool nameIsOk;

        using ( var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction() )
        {
            var model = (BlockTableRecord) tr.GetObject(SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(db), OpenMode.ForRead);
            foreach ( ObjectId id in model )
            {
                if ( id.ObjectClass.DxfName == "TEXT" )
                {
                    var text = (DBText) tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    if ( text.TextString == sectionName )
                    {
                        nameIsOk = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                    if ( id.ObjectClass.DxfName == "MTEXT" )
                    {
                        {
                            var mtext = (MText) tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite);

                            if ( mtext.Text == sectionName )
                            {
                                nameIsOk = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nameIsOk = false;

                    }
            }

            tr.Commit();
        }

        return nameIsOk;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас есть 2 варианта:

Первый это: Присвоить переменной `nameIsOk` начальное значение *(при инициализации)*.

```
bool isNameOk = false;
```

И второй вариант это присвоить значение в случае если `mtext.Text != sectionName`

```
//...
if ( mtext.Text == sectionName )
{
    nameIsOk = true;
}
//...
```

Добавить ещё блок `else` т.к. если вот тут условие не выполниться *(`mtext.Text != sectionName`)*, то переменная `nameIsOk` останется фактически пустой. Да, ей будет дано стандартное значение для данного типа *(у нас это `false`*). Но студия делает предупреждение дабы избежать ошибок. Так что, выбирайте один из более подходящий вариантов для вашего метода. Я оставлю код для первого варианта:

```
public bool CheckTheSectionName(string sectionName)
{
    var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    var db = doc.Database;
    var ed = doc.Editor;
    bool nameIsOk = default(bool); //or bool nameIsOk = default; for C# 7.1

    using ( var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction() )
    {
        var model = (BlockTableRecord) tr.GetObject(SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(db), OpenMode.ForRead);
        foreach ( ObjectId id in model )
        {
            if ( id.ObjectClass.DxfName == "TEXT" )
            {
                var text = (DBText) tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);
                if ( text.TextString == sectionName )
                    nameIsOk = true;
            }
            else if ( id.ObjectClass.DxfName == "MTEXT" )
            {
                var mtext = (MText) tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                if ( mtext.Text == sectionName )
                {
                    nameIsOk = true;
                }
            }
            else
                nameIsOk = false;
        }

        tr.Commit();
    }
    return nameIsOk; //If mtext != sectionName method will return false. 
}
```

Comment: А можно кстати сделать блок `try/finally` внутри `using`, и в `finally` часть поместить `tr.Commit();` - это серьезно сократит код, и в таком случае в нужных местах сразу организовывать выход `return true/false`

Comment: @NewView да, конечно можно, но вопрос та в другом. Я пояснил почему данная ошибка появляется. А в самих блоках я тоже запутался, так что ваша правка может быть принята.

Comment: Нет, нет, оставим вашу, она по сути правильная, но код автора слишком громоздкий для такой задачи, слишком много ненужных переменных, ИМХО конечно

Comment: @NewView думаю вы все же правы =)